# Xamarin Forms shared ControlTemplate for ContentPage and CarouselPage

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, controltemplate, controltemplates, control-template

I'm stuck trying to reuse an control template for a independent `ContentPage` as well as a `ContentPage` in a `CarouselPage`...

The main problem is that the `CarouselPage` doesn't support the `ControlTemplate` property. Therefore I'm forced to insert a `ContentPage` in the `DataTemplate` of the `CarouselPage`. This `ContentPage` then can get the `ControlTemplate` assigned but I run into the problem that the `BindingContext` is not the root of the `ViewModel`.

I'll also try to explain the issues with code:

I've create the template as shown below.

```xaml
<!-- Loader view template -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LoaderViewTemplate">
    <AbsoluteLayout Padding="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <!-- Content -->
        <ContentPresenter AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

        <!-- Loader -->
        <BoxView IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.IsBusy}" BackgroundColor="Green" Opacity="0.5" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
        <StackLayout IsVisible="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.IsBusy}" Padding="6" BackgroundColor="Gray" Orientation="Horizontal" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, -1, -1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
            <ActivityIndicator Color="White" IsRunning="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.IsBusy}" VerticalOptions="Center" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" />
            <Label TextColor="White" Text="Loading..." VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>

    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The template is **working correctly** for the `ContentPage` shown below.

```xaml
<ContentPage ...
             ControlTemplate="{StaticResource LoaderViewTemplate}">

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        ...
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

But it **doesn't work** in the `CarouselPage` as shown below.

```xaml
<CarouselPage ...
              ItemsSource="{Binding Tournament.Rounds}">

    <CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPage ControlTemplate="{StaticResource LoaderViewTemplate}">
                ...
            </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>

</CarouselPage>
```

The `BindingContext` in the `CarouselPage` becomes a `TournamentRoundModel` from the `Tournament.Rounds` collection.

Does any one has an idea on how I can reach the root of the `ViewModel` within the independent `ContentPage` and the `CarouselPage` nested `ContentPage`?

Kind regards,
Jop Middelkamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all if you need each `ContentPage` in `CarousalPage` to be able to refer to the root view-model, while providing the same to the `ControlTemplate`'s binding(s).

Simplest way to do that would be to extend `ContentPage` to support a bindable property to hold this reference (to root view-model).

```
public class ExContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty RootViewModelProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "RootViewModel", typeof(object), typeof(ExContentPage),
            defaultValue: default(object));

    public object RootViewModel
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(RootViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RootViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then you can update your shared control-template as:

```
<!-- Loader view template -->
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LoaderViewTemplate">
    <AbsoluteLayout Padding = "0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

        <!-- Content -->
        <ContentPresenter .. />

        < !--Loader-- >
        <BoxView IsVisible= "{TemplateBinding RootViewModel.IsBusy}" BackgroundColor= "Green" .. />

        <StackLayout IsVisible= "{TemplateBinding RootViewModel.IsBusy}" .. >
            <ActivityIndicator Color= "White" IsRunning= "{TemplateBinding RootViewModel.IsBusy}"  />
            <Label TextColor= "White" Text= "Loading..." VerticalOptions= "Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Sample usage would look like:

```
<local:ExContentPage ...
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomNamespace"     
        RootViewModel="{Binding}"
         ControlTemplate="{StaticResource LoaderViewTemplate}">

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions = "Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</local:ExContentPage>
```

and,

```
<CarouselPage...
             x:Name="Parent" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Tournament.Rounds}">
    <CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ExContentPage
                ControlTemplate = "{StaticResource LoaderViewTemplate}"
                RootViewModel="{Binding BindingContext, Source={x:Reference Parent}}">
                ...
            </ContentPage>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselPage.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselPage>
```

Furthermore, if `IsBusy` is the only property that you need to refer in `ControlTemplate` - you can create an `IsBusy` bindable property in extended content-page; instead of `RootViewModel`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing anything carousel related i would suggest you use this nuget package https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView instead of the default carousel page.

Comment: I've just been switching from the CarouselView to CarouselPage because the CarouselView is to buggy. When pressing an entry on any but the first page the CarouselView control is moving away from the active view... Not workable and confirming the prerelease NuGet status.

Comment: @JopMiddelkamp yes.i totally agree with you. CarouselView doesnt support the listview when the template created by xaml. it s interesting. And as you told, its moving away from the active view